# Swift 4 - Nesting JSON Response for Class Structure into TableViewCell

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I've got the following structures to aid in returning data from a JSON web api:

```
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
//   let story = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Story.self, from: jsonData)

import Foundation

typealias Story = [StoryElement]

struct StoryElement: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let storyPublic, featured: Bool
    let added, modified: String
    let itemType: ItemType
    let collection: JSONNull?
    let owner: Owner
    let files: Files
    let tags: [ItemType]
    let elementTexts: [ElementText]
    let extendedResources: ExtendedResources

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, url
        case storyPublic = "public"
        case featured, added, modified
        case itemType = "item_type"
        case collection, owner, files, tags
        case elementTexts = "element_texts"
        case extendedResources = "extended_resources"
    }
}

struct ElementText: Codable {
    let html: Bool
    let text: String
    let elementSet: ElementSet
    let element: Element

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case html, text
        case elementSet = "element_set"
        case element
    }
}

struct Element: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url, name: String
    let resource: ElementResource
}

enum ElementResource: String, Codable {
    case elements = "elements"
}

struct ElementSet: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url: URL
    let name: Name
    let resource: ElementSetResource
}

enum Name: String, Codable {
    case dublinCore = "Dublin Core"
    case itemTypeMetadata = "Item Type Metadata"
}

enum ElementSetResource: String, Codable {
    case elementSets = "element_sets"
}

enum URL: String, Codable {
    case httpWWWRalstoncemeteryCOMGreeleyAPIElementSets1 = "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/element_sets/1"
    case httpWWWRalstoncemeteryCOMGreeleyAPIElementSets3 = "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/element_sets/3"
}

struct ExtendedResources: Codable {
    let exhibitPages: Files
    let geolocations: Owner

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case exhibitPages = "exhibit_pages"
        case geolocations
    }
}

struct Files: Codable {
    let count: Int
    let url, resource: String
}

struct Owner: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url, resource: String
}

struct ItemType: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url, name, resource: String
}

// MARK: Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable {
    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

You can see the JSON output I am working with, as well as the original structures here: https://app.quicktype.io?share=oAMNjooSzgpraWpf1KIj (just for reference).

The data (I believe) is returned successfully and parsed correctly, the only issue comes down to myself not being as familiar (I'm in the process of trying to learn a bit more).

So I have a TableViewController and in that I have a cell with the following coded into it:

```
struct StoryCellViewModel {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let storyPublic, featured: Bool
    let added, modified: String
}
```

And in the actual TableViewController under the viewDidLoad() I have this portion of script:

```
 print(story)
                self.cellViewModels = story.map{
                    StoryCellViewModel(id: $0.id, url: $0.url, storyPublic: $0.storyPublic, featured: $0.featured, added: $0.added, modified: $0.modified)
                }
```

and a little bit lower than that, I have:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoryCell", for: indexPath)

    let cellViewModel = cellViewModels[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(cellViewModel.id)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = cellViewModel.modified


    return cell
}
```

I will make it known that all of this works, the id and modified (both just being used as tests to ensure the connection and printing works properly) are fine, but my question comes up here:

If we go back to the structures there is this portion:

```
struct ElementText: Codable {
    let html: Bool
    let text: String
    let elementSet: ElementSet
    let element: Element

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case html, text
        case elementSet = "element_set"
        case element
    }
}
```

Which refers to the following portion of example JSON:

```
"element_texts": [
      {
        "html": false,
        "text": "Woehler and Force Farm Equipment Building",
        "element_set": {
          "id": 1,
          "url": "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/element_sets/1",
          "name": "Dublin Core",
          "resource": "element_sets"
        },
        "element": {
          "id": 50,
          "url": "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/elements/50",
          "name": "Title",
          "resource": "elements"
        }
      },
      {
        "html": false,
        "text": "Woehler and Force Farm Equipment",
        "element_set": {
          "id": 1,
          "url": "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/element_sets/1",
          "name": "Dublin Core",
          "resource": "element_sets"
        },
        "element": {
          "id": 39,
          "url": "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/elements/39",
          "name": "Creator",
          "resource": "elements"
        }
      },
      {
        "html": false,
        "text": "Street view of the front exterior of Woehler and Force Farm Equipment. Several automobiles are visible through the windows of the store. The alley along the side of the building is also visible. There are several signs along the front of the building reading, 'Farm Equipment,' 'Kaiser Frazer W&F,' and 'Woehler & Force.'; Verso There is a sticker with typed black ink reading, 'Woehler & Force 1316-22 8th Ave. - Greeley, CO 1947. Orig. env. says Liberty Trucker Parts Co./ 690 Lincoln St./F.V. Altwater/POB 1889/Denver, Colo.'",
        "element_set": {
          "id": 3,
          "url": "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/element_sets/3",
          "name": "Item Type Metadata",
          "resource": "element_sets"
        },
        "element": {
          "id": 54,
          "url": "http://www.ralstoncemetery.com/greeley/api/elements/54",
          "name": "Story",
          "resource": "elements"
        }
      }
    ],
```

**So my question is: ** How would I go about printing out say the first of the `element_texts` (The one that has "Woehler and Force Farm Equipment Building" set for the `text` field)?

If there is any further explanation required, I'll be happy to type it up. Or if anyone has any resources for this level of nesting, I'd be very grateful. Thank you -

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question has a lot of code in it - to help others answer your questions consider only including critical components of your code related to the problem. People who want to help don't want to read through all this as you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

- `story` is an array of `StoryElement` (why not `stories`?)
- The type of property `elementTexts` in `StoryElement` is an array of `ElementText`

So basically you need two loops to iterate over `story` and `elementTexts`

```
for aStory in story {
    for elementText in aStory.elementTexts {
        print(elementText.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in "CellForRowat" call let cell =  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath etc.

then place text in cell.text

Answer (score 0):

Create a array like this . `var AllTexts = [String]()`

you can fetch json data so many ways like JsonDecode/JSONSerialization, i am using JSONSerialization. After fetching data i am appending text values in to array.

```
 do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String: Any]
            for (key,value) in jsonResult {
                 print(key)
                  if let result2:[[String:Any]] = value as? [[String:Any]]{
                     for dict in result2 {

                        for (key,value) in dict {
                              if key == "text" {
                                 self.AllTexts.append(value as! String)
                             }
                        }
                    }
                  }
            }
            print(self.AllTexts)
        } catch {
            // handle error
            print(error)
        }
```